# LG G4 can't fastboot/reboot bootloader

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader, flashtool

Ola!

I'm playing with a LG G4-H815.

When using `adb reboot bootloader`, the phone just boot on normal mode.
When doing the Volume Up + Power button thing, I manage to land on Download Mode but nothing happens, `fastboot` does not detect the phone. And I get this popup:

[image: Popup when in Download Mode]

Reset Factory doesn't work either. Does nothing but reboot the phone as if nothing happened.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.5-5949299
Installed as /home/adrien/adb-fastboot/platform-tools/adb
```

```
$ fastboot --version
fastboot version 29.0.5-5949299
Installed as /home/adrien/adb-fastboot/platform-tools/fastboot
```

Comment: maybe it's a silly question from me, but have you installed the correct drivers on your operating system? do you have the latest adb and fastboot tools too? (if possible add more details about your environment OS name & version, adb exe version, fastboot version..)

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's relevant but when I plug my phone, it is recognized and I can explore it via my native file manager. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with lastest version of adb and fastboot. (OP updated) Also, I did not find how to install the drivers for Ubuntu. I've tried though but maybe not hard enough!

Comment: did LG removed fastboot mode from your model?

Comment: @alecxs No idea. I found writings on the web mentioning it was possible so I guess not but I can't guarantee anything.

Comment: From "normal mode" try the adb reboot bootloader command. Then try fastboot devices. If still just rebooting into "normal mode" then for the adb reboot command try `adb reboot-bootloader`  instead of adb reboot bootloader.

Comment: @BoLawson I did, and as I expected there is no difference in the results. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Just semantics in syntax. It depends on the developer really. Scanning over everything I noticed your using a Linux machine. Have you setup or checked to see if `udev` rules are correct?

Comment: @BoLawson No, I did not. I'll see if I have time to check it. I switched to another phone and gave up on this since then so I'm not sure I will but heh...